# DynamicJasper: background color based on value

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Is it possible to set the Background color of specific cell using given color for each row using DynamicJasper API?

If the object **Product** has { id, price, name, *color*} attributes 
then the background color of the *name* field need to be change to *color* field's value. (JasperReports supports this behavior)

Answer (score 1):

**Guidelines:**

In this Solution, a List of all the possible colors is being generated before the creation of the report., 
The column coloredCell has its own value and also the color value (represented as a field).
all colors are HexString.
DynamicJasperReport.java

```
   public class DynamicJasperReport{
     public DynamicJasperReport(List<String> color){
        DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();
        ArrayList<ConditionalStyle> listCondStyle = StyleUtils.getConditonalStyles(color);
        AbstractColumn col = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                            .setColumnProperty("colordCell", Object.class.getName())
                            .setTitle("Colored Cell")
                            .addConditionalStyles(listCondStyle)
                            .build();
   //adding the color value
        drb.addField("color", Boolean.class.getName());
    }


   }
```

**ConditionStyleExpression:**
BackgroundCondition.java

```
   public class BackgroundCondition  extends ConditionStyleExpression implements CustomExpression {
       private String fieldName;
       private String colorValue;

       public BackgroundCondition(String fieldName, String colorValue) {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.colorValue = colorValue;
}

       public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
    boolean condition = false;
    Object currentValue = fields.get(fieldName);
    if (currentValue instanceof String) {
        String s = (String) currentValue;
        condition = colorValue.equals(currentValue);
    }
    return condition;
}

       public String getClassName() {
         return Boolean.class.getName();
      }
   }
```

StyleUtils.java:

```
  public abstract class StyleUtils {
   public static Style backgroundColorStyle (String hexColor){
     Style cellBackgroundStyle = new Style();
     cellBackgroundStyle.setTransparency(Transparency.OPAQUE);
     cellBackgroundStyle.setBackgroundColor(Color.decode(hexColor));
     cellBackgroundStyle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     cellBackgroundStyle.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.TOP);
     return cellBackgroundStyle;
    }

   public static ArrayList<ConditionalStyle> getConditonalStyles(List<String> Color) {
    ArrayList<ConditionalStyle> conditionalStyles = new ArrayList<ConditionalStyle>();
    Color.forEach(c-> {
        BackgroundCondition backgroundCondition = new BackgroundCondition("color", c);
        ConditionalStyle cs = new ConditionalStyle(backgroundCondition, StyleUtils.backgroundColorStyle(c));
        conditionalStyles.add(cs);

    });
    return conditionalStyles;
}
  }
```